# looking to compare string[] splitted if it exists in List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList

Tags: c#, list

I am looking to compare `string[] splitted` if it exists in `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList`. IF it does not then I would add it to `List<string>` as a seperate list of email addresses.

using LINQ might be a good option, please help with implementaion.

looking to compare `string[] splitted` if it exists in `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` myList

```
  public void SendEmails(String esmails)
{
  //splitting email string 
  string[] splitted = esmails.Emails.Split(new string[] { System.Environment.NewLine },     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> myList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

  foreach (var email in GetEmails)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Count(); i++)
    {
      if (email.EmailAddress.Equals(splitted[i].Replace(";","")))
          myList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(email.IdentificationNo, email.EmailAddress));

    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Your code does not compile. `esmails` is declared as string but is accessed like this `esmails.Emails.Split(...)`. But `String` does not have a member `Emails`.

Answer (score 0):

Use implicitly typed variable (var) if possible

You can achieve this by using join

```
public void SendEmails(String esmails)
{
    //splitting email string 
    var splitted = 
        esmails.Split(new []{System.Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(s => s.Replace(";", ""));

    var matchings = 
            from s in splitted
            join email in GetEmails on email.EmailAddress equals s
            select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(email.IdentificationNo, email.EmailAddress);

    var myList = matchings.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SendEmails(String esmails)
{
    List<String> split = esmails.Split(new String[] { System.Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Replace(";", "")).ToList();

Dictionary<Int32, String> dictionary = new Dictionary<Int32, String>();

foreach (Email email in GetEmails())
{
    foreach (String address in split)
    {
        if (email.EmailAddress.Equals(address))
            dictionary[email.IdentificationNo] = email.EmailAddress;
    }
```

}